# Wordpress with PHP Class using init: how to pass variables between functions?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, class, init

I would like to break apart the function used in Class to make it easier to understand, however I cant seem to work out how to pass variables across between two or more functions while maintaining the WP INIT hook. I have simplified my code for this question.

I am not sure if using multiple add_action in __construct is the correct way to go about it.

Thanks.

```
//called from template/index.php
do_action('foo');

//in template/fuctions.php
add_action( 'init', array ( 'foo', 'init' ) );

class foo
{

 public $stillnotworking;

    public static function init()
    {
        new self;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action( 'foo', array ( $this, 'part1' ) );
        add_action( 'foo', array ( $this, 'part2' ) );
    }

    public function part1()
    {
      $this->x = '123';
      $stillnotworking = '123';
    }

    public function part2()
    {          
        echo $this->x; //not working
        echo $stillnotworking;          
    }

    public function __toString()
    {          
        echo $this->x; //not working
        echo $stillnotworking;          
    }

    function __destruct() {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declare your `$x` within you class. Try

```
add_action( 'init', array ( 'foo', 'init' ) );

class foo
{

 public $x; 
 public $stillnotworking;

public static function init()
{
    new self;
}

public function __construct()
{
    add_action( 'foo', array ( $this, 'part1' ) );
    add_action( 'foo', array ( $this, 'part2' ) );
}

public function part1()
{
  $this->x = '123';
  $stillnotworking = '123';
}

public function part2()
{          
    echo $this->x; //not working
    echo $stillnotworking;          
}

public function __toString()
{          
    echo $this->x; //not working
    echo $stillnotworking;          
}

function __destruct() {

}

}
```